# What is a good way to bench test a mesh network?

Tags: mesh-network, microwave

I've been experimenting with some 2.4ghz based mesh networks similar to http://hsmm-mesh.org/. I'd like to have something on the bench where I could simulate roving between nodes, and create hidden nodes and varying signal strengths.

Is there a better solution than a network of coax cables with splitters and attenuators (variable and fixed)? Any pitfalls in this approach (I'm turning the power way down and using a lot of attenuation)? Any suggestions on how to build a setup like this without breaking the bank (the attenuators and splitters get expensive!)?

Answer (score 8):

You can simulate. The idea is to model your RF channel(s) numerically by adding things like [AWGN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_white_Gaussian_noise), [multipath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipath_interference), [clock skew](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_skew), and so on. And, you want a way to model a lot of these channels, and twiddle the parameters and see how the system responds.

There are many software libraries out there that will make this easier. I'd suggest [GNU Radio](http://gnuradio.org/redmine/projects/gnuradio/wiki). It has blocks that can be chained together to model an RF channel, and blocks to implement most basic digital modulation schemes. It has a graphical interface where you can connect them together, which is good for experimentation, and it also has bindings to several programming languages so you can automate the creation of a complex network of channels and implement your own blocks. It also has blocks to interface to real hardware, like the [USRP](http://ettus.com/), or an audio card that can in turn interface to inexpensive SDR platforms like [Softrock](http://wb5rvz.com/sdr/).

[image: GNU Radio screenshot]
*[image source](http://pwnhome.wordpress.com/tag/gnuradio/)*

If you also want to simulate the OS running the hardware on your nodes, you'll need a somewhat more powerful computer, and a way to programatically create virtual machines. Again, many options, but for an easy start, I'd look at [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/). With this, you could conceivably create a handful of virtual nodes, each running virtual RF interfaces implemented by GNU Radio.

Comment: +1: Simulation should probably be **the** de facto first step in a developing a system

Comment: +1: Nice pointer to Vagrant, a good package for team developement and/of complex testing procedures.